# classic asp | VBScript - SELECT 80040e10 error

Tags: vbscript

I have a really simple select statement from an Access db :

```
sqlopen = "select * from master WHERE keycodecond = SbmitVal ;"
```

which fails with "80040e10  No value given for one or more required parameters."

if, however I run with this (i.e. replacing SbmitVal with 2) it works

```
sqlopen = "select * from master WHERE keycodecond = 2 ;"
```

nb SbmitVal is also valued at 2 when I interrogate it - but as the "keycodecond" value is an Autonumber field, I presume it's something to do with a data mismatch, but I need keycodecond to test against a variable... if someone might be able to advise I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sqlopen = "select * from master WHERE keycodecond = " & SbmitVal & ";"
```

It looks as though you're not sending the variable `SbmitVal`, you're literally sending the word `SbmitVal`.

It's generally better to parameterise your queries too, although not having used Access DB I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: Duhhhh thank you so much - that worked!!!! I feel silly and grateful in equal measure - thanks again!